# Including "ThisWorkbook" code in Excel add-in

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on creating a VBA Excel-Add in. I require the use of the "Workbook_SheetChange" Sub. Is it possible to include this code as a portion of the add-in so that all workbooks where the add-in containing user defined functions are used have access to the code that executes on a sheet change?

The file is being saved as a .xla add-in. However "Workbook_SheetChange" will not work from a module, and must be in the ThisWorkbook code section of a file. Thus it is not carried over with my add-in currently.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using the built in vba module of excel or are you using vb.net with visual studio to create an add in with a ribbon and such

Comment: Built in module - the only thing the add-in does is bring in user defined functions for all workbooks

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on what your goal is. Can you clarify with a few more sentences in the question text?

Comment: I found a link vba add ins http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/379566-can-i-share-a-vba-module-for-multi-workbooks.html are you saving the project as a .xla file

Comment: Does a VBA add in have the notion of an Application module?(COMAddIn) if so you should try moving the code referencing ThisWorkbook and sheet changed up the class hierarchy.

Comment: Is it possible to change the reference of ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook. The This pointer losses its meaning outside the context of one Workbook. ActiveWorkbook should reference the workbook that was last selected and would be the natural book the user would see.

Comment: From msdn ||| expression.SheetChange(Sh, Target) |||
expression An expression that returns a Workbook object. ||| This implies there should be a work around from using the ThisWorkbook module and reference the code using a standard workbook variable or ActiveWorkbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a custom class module in your add-in that has an Application variable declared WithEvents. I usually call my class module CAppEvents.

```
Private WithEvents mxlApp As Application

Public Property Set App(xlApp As Application)

    Set mxlApp = xlApp

End Property
```

Now in the top left drop down of the code pane (Ctrl+F2), you have mxlApp. Select that and tab over to the top right drop down and choose SheetChange. You'll get a stub like this.

```
Private Sub mxlApp_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

If any cell on any sheet in any open workbook changes, this event will fire. You'll want to add some code to make sure it's a sheet you care about. You don't get the workbook name in the arguments, but you can use `Sh.Parent` to access the workbook.

The only other thing you need is to create the class. In a standard module

```
Public gclsAppEvents As CAppEvents

Sub Auto_Open()

    Set gclsAppEvents = New CAppEvents
    Set gclsAppEvents.App = Application

End Sub
```

Making the variable public makes it stay in scope while you're add-in is loaded. Any sub in a standard module named Auto_Open will run when the workbook is first opened.

Comment: When you select a column (by clicking on the column header), and press `DEL` key to remove the content of the entire column, the `mxlApp_SheetChange` procedure is called with a Range containing millions of cells, even though the cells that actually changed are just a few. Then, iterating over those millions of cells takes so long that Excel stops responding and your only way out of that is killing the whole Excel process.

Answer (score -1):

This solve my problem

code add into the .xlam

```
dim currentworkbook as Workbook
set currentworkbook = activeworkbook
```

then set all your variable that want to link to current workbook as currentworkbook.

then will be functioning well.

dont use thisWorkbook, as it will locate your .xlam file as thisWorkbook instead of the one you really want to run it.